# Mybatis - getting results with type info

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am using `spring-boot-mybatis-starter`.  At this moment I am fairly familiar with mybatis, however I am searching for possibility getting info about types of columns returned results.  Is it possible ?

For example, I am getting `Hashmap<String, Object> results` - I would like to know what is type of `Object` not using `instance of`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the actual java types in the results: `Class c = null == results.get("columnName") ? null : results.get("columnName").getClass();`

If you want to know about SQL types, I fear you cannot. This requires accessing resultset metadata, and this what Mybatis does, because this is its job. The only control you could have in the mapping processing is when using custom type handlers, but they are used for very specific cases.
For at least 95% use cases, Mybatis maps standard SQL type to simple java types, better let it do its job. Even though, as far as I know, there are no logs in mapping classes. (Mybatis lack few logs in my opinion).

And it could be helpful if you explain the purpose behind this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table column type from information schema as follows.

```
SELECT column_name, column_type 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where table_schema='[Table_schema]' and table_name='[Table_Name]'.
```

Hope it helps.